# How can I get stored session values in multiple Struts 2 action classes?

Tags: java, session, struts2, struts

How can I get stored session values in multiple Struts 2 action classes?

**I do *not* want to use `SessionAware` interface in all the actions.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have three options:

1. Do it right and use `SessionAware`.
2. Do it right and use a base action class that uses `SessionAware`.
3. Do it wrong and use `ActionContext`:

```java
Map attibutes = ActionContext.getContext().getSession();
```

Documented on the Struts 2 wiki under [How do we get access to the session](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/how-do-we-get-access-to-the-session.html).

Why *wouldn't* you want to use `SessionAware` and make your actions more-easily testable?

Comment: Hi Dave, Good to know diff ways ,once I will put some Key-value in session map with in one Action ,Will I be able to get that same value by using key in Different which is not using/implementing SessionAware interface. ?

Comment: @user1859100  Session is session, regardless of how accessed.

Answer (score 0):

### If you don't want to use `SessionAware` in multiple classes then at least you can use one abstract class or interface your action classes extend. It will inject  a `SessionMap` to your action class instances.

Other ways to obtain a `SessionMap` or directly `HttpSession` are from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25712483/573032):

> If you want to put something to the session you should get the session map from the action context
>
> ```
> Map<String, Object> session = >ActionContext.getContext().getSession();
> session.put("username", username);
> session.put("role", 1);
> ```
>
> or use servlet session directly
>
> ```
> HttpSession session = >ServletActionContext.getRequest().getSession(); 
> session.setAttribute("username", username);
> session.setAttribute("role", 1);
> ```
>
> But the first case is preferable, due to it's supported by the framework.

---

More other options (you have at least another five options):

- implement the [`scopedModelDriven` interceptor](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/scoped-model-driven-interceptor.html);
- use [`scope` interceptor](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/scope-interceptor.html);
- use scoped [bean configuration](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/bean-configuration.html) and [inject](http://struts.apache.org/core-developers/dependency-injection.html) it to the action;
- use custom annotation (i.e [Conversation plugin](https://code.google.com/p/struts2-conversation/wiki/SessionScope))
- use [Spring plugin](https://struts.apache.org/plugins/spring/) and use spring [bean scopes](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s04.html).